# Azure Function v3 .NET Core 3.1 ServiceBusTrigger "Message processing error (Action=RenewLock)" even though autoComplete = false

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, queuetrigger

I have a queue trigger that runs a long running task.  Ran into all sorts of problems with lock durations and renewal, so I decided to manually complete the message at the very start of the whole process.  If the job encounters an error, send the message back to the queue.

In the Log Data below, you can see it gets the message, completes it, starts the task, logs a `lock supplied is invalid` error which seems to affect nothing, then completes the task. I want to stop this error.  It's annoying.

```cs
[FunctionName("QueueTrigger")]
public async Task RunQueue([ServiceBusTrigger("queuename", Connection = "cn")] Message message, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, [ServiceBus("queuename", Connection = "cn")] IAsyncCollector<Message> queue)
{
    var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestObj>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body));
    logger.LogInfo("*** Before complete");
    await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
    logger.LogInfo("*** After complete");
    try
    {
        if(msg.Whatever > 1)   throw new Exception("Bogus exception thrown for testing.");

        var result = await RunTheTask(msg);
        if (!result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            logger.LogError(result.Failure);
            throw new ApplicationException(result.Failure);
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        logger.LogInfo("*** About to requeue");
        await queue.AddAsync(new Message(message.Body));
        logger.LogSuccess("*** Queued the message again.");
    }
}
```

`host.json` file has `serviceBus` config like so (turning `autoComplete` off)

```json
"serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 1,
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": false,
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 1
      },
      "SessionHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": false
      },
      "BatchOptions": {
        "AutoComplete": false
      }
```

In both cases, the code works as expected, but again in both cases I always see an "invalid lock" error

Some log stuff:

```
[2021-02-01T20:46:27.248Z] Executing 'QueueTrigger' (Reason='(null)', Id=520a670c-e636-49b8-96b5-7502f6b479ac)
[2021-02-01T20:46:27.251Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: d7af56ed083947e99ce0fc468f111e4d, SequenceNumber: 37, DeliveryCount: 1, EnqueuedTimeUtc: 2021-02-01T20:40:44.5390000Z, LockedUntilUtc: 2021-02-01T20:41:44.5550000Z, SessionId: (null)
[2021-02-01T20:46:28.331Z] *** Before complete
[2021-02-01T20:46:28.471Z] *** After complete
[2021-02-01T20:46:28.498Z] Running the Task
[2021-02-01T20:46:28.826Z] Message processing error (Action=RenewLock, ClientId=whatever, EntityPath=queueName, Endpoint=blah.servicebus.windows.net)
[2021-02-01T20:46:28.830Z] Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus: The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue. Reference:30780d70-2887-4923-8725-329ab94dd4b2, TrackingId:e3e85f42-1c62-44da-b858-1c856f972a1f_B14, SystemTracker:x:Queue:queueName, Timestamp:2021-02-01T20:40:46.
[2021-02-01T20:46:38.855Z] Finished the Task
[2021-02-01T20:46:42.221Z] Executed 'QueueTrigger' (Succeeded, Id=520a670c-e636-49b8-96b5-7502f6b479ac, Duration=14992ms)
```

Comment: Is your processing taking longer than 5 minutes than you need to complete the message before you process it? It sort of defeats the idea of Peek-Lock mode and also not very safe.

Comment: Doesn't typically take longer than 5 minutes, but it could.  That's why I just mark the message as complete as soon as I get it, then I don't care how long it takes.

Comment: Have you tried to read the data first and then complete the message? Alternatively, clone it rather than using its body.

Comment: There isn't an issue getting the message, reading the content, completing the message, running the task, or re-queueing a message if I need to.  The problem is that even though I'm manually calling `CompleteAsync`, the underlying plumbing somewhere is still trying to access the message.  It's probably not affecting anything, but I don't want the error to occur.

Comment: I'd raise an issue in https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension to see if that's a bug or not.

Comment: Hi, have you try to put the 'complete' method at the end of function?

Comment: Logged an issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/issues/137

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move the 'complete' method to the end, the function will automatically refresh the lock expiration time to keep it available under normal circumstances. But once you use the 'complete' method, the function will generate the last lock, and if your subsequent logic exceeds the lock time, a lock expiration exception will be thrown. You can look at the following code and compare using complete and not using complete The difference:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp71
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("queuename", Connection = "cn")] Message message, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, [ServiceBus("queuename", Connection = "cn")] IAsyncCollector<Message> queue, ILogger logger)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("When the message comes in, the expire time is: "+message.SystemProperties.LockedUntilUtc.ToString());//Now the time is 2/4/2021 8:29:00 AM

            Thread.Sleep(6000);

            logger.LogInformation("After 6 seconds, the expired time is :"+message.SystemProperties.LockedUntilUtc.ToString());//The time of the lock is renewed, so now the time is 2/4/2021 8:29:04 AM

            //When you complete the message, there is no way to renew the lock because the lock is not exist(Azure function stop renew the lock.).
            await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
            logger.LogInformation("After complete the message, the expired time is :"+message.SystemProperties.LockedUntilUtc.ToString());//Now the time is still 2/4/2021 8:29:04 AM

            Thread.Sleep(6 * 1000);//Your try catch is here.

            logger.LogInformation("After complete message and 6 seconds later, the expired time is :"+message.SystemProperties.LockedUntilUtc.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I get the message, deserialize the body, then complete the message. I don't care about the message beyond that and don't interact with it nor the `MessageReceiver`. I'm not causing the error by any interaction through my code.

Comment: @DevonS I have change the answer, I think you can put the 'complete' method to the end instead of the function. The problem should comes from the function don't renew the lock because of the message is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Logged an issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/issues/137
Issue has a link to a repo to repro.